Protect pdf file for only logged in user in nginx wordpress
I need to protect pdf file for only logged in user
I have redirected all pdf files to php file and i need to open file if logged in
 if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    // redirect to login page or show the message + login form
    die; // or exit, wp_redirect etc
}
 
$var= $_GET["file"];
 $file = 'https://test.com/'.$var;
$filename = 'tst.pdf'; 
  
// Header content type 
header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 
  
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"'); 
  
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
  
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes'); 
  
// Read the file 
@readfile($file); 

but it was not working

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to describe what you mean by "it was not working" - does that mean the file doesn't return using the headers you're using, or does that mean something else?  You need a more complete description of the problem.
